# Locally convex or concave function and differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If we define a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, locally convex at a point $x$, if there exist an interval around $x$ in which $f$ is convex,

will $f$ differentiable imply $f$ is locally convex or locally concave?

Comment: IS local convexity a mainstream definition?  It's interesting but I'm curious.

Comment: I don't know. I just wanted to know this as for locally convex function at least, we can always say that tangent line will locally touch the graph only at a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f =  x^3 $ is differentiable at $x=0$ but nether locally convex nor concave around $x=0$

**P.S:** If you are eager to find conditions implying local convexity or concavity, one sufficient condition is $f$ being $C^2$ then  for every $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $f'' (x) \neq 0 $ then $f$ is either locally convex or concave around $x$. But be carful that this cannot be generalized to functions with several arguments unfortunately. That's the reason why many optimization algorithms do not converge in multidimensional spaces unless under some conditions.

Comment: sorry missed something in question to add