# Convexity at a point

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

This is more likely a fact-finding question. Consider a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in[a,b]$. Is there any notion of convexity at the point $c$?

Comment: No.  Convexity (as I'm sure you know) involves the criterion that linear combinations of *two* (or more) points like in the space.  So convexity can apply to a *space* in which a point $x$ lies, but the definition is not appropriate at a single point taken alone.

Comment: As David G. Stork noted, convexity of a function is a global notion. However, you could reasonably define a function to be convex at a point, if it is convex in some neighborhood of that point.

Comment: A twice differentiable function will be (strictly) convex near a point if $f''>0$ at that point. I suppose you could call $f''\geq0$ "convex" at a point. Then if it is "convex" at each point of an interval it will be convex on the interval. But then also $x^3$ is "convex" at $0$ without being convex on any neighborhood of it.

Comment: "Local convexity" is not a usual concept for a function (there is the concept of locally convex spaces). However we find it in this Mathematical Programming glossary: https://glossary.informs.org/ver2/mpgwiki/index.php/Locally_convex_function. It was also mentionned in an MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634452/locally-convex-or-concave-function-and-differentiable-function. I have the feeling that convexity is especially useful as a global property rather than as a local one.

Comment: See (v) at top of p. 177 and “4. Pointwise Defect of Convexity” on pp. 187−194 of: Ban/Gal, [*On some pointwise defects of properties in real analysis*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-29/issue-1/On-some-pointwise-defects-of-properties-in-real-analysis/rae/1149860183.full), **Real Analysis Exchange** 29 #1 (2003-2004), pp. 175−197. Also Pong/Raianu, [*Convexity at a point*](https://ssmr.ro/bulletin/pdf/66-2/articol_7.pdf), **Bull. Math. Soc. Sci. Math. Roumanie** 66 (114) #2 (2023), pp. 235−250 **(continued)**

Comment: given in [Wai Yan Pong’s](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1304580/wai-yan-pong) deleted answer is an especially nice treatment of several pointwise notions of convexity. Curiously, despite having 22 references, Pong/Raianu overlooked the Ban/Gal paper, which is published in a journal well-known for real analysis minutiae like this.

Comment: Regarding two standard ways to go from an interval (or global) function notion to a local type of notion, see [this 16 May 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9kU61P-TLOs/m/H7bsXeNAHrkJ). There I discuss the notion of "increasing at a point" (well-known) and something I called "increasing near a point" (for lack of anything else to call it; the notion is not particularly useful as far as I know). For many real analysis pointwise properties of better known interval properties, see my comment in [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457877/15780).

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered it in 'Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms' by Bazaraa, where it is defined as follows:

$$
f(x) \textrm{ is convex at } x' 
$$
$$
\iff
$$
$$ 
\forall \lambda \in [0,1], \forall x: f(\lambda x' + (1-\lambda)x) \leq \lambda f(x')+ (1-\lambda)f(x)
$$
So essentially the same definition as normal convexity, with the difference that one of the ends of the line segment is fixed at $x'$.

In the book I mentioned above the concept is used in some KKT-related optimality conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few notions of convexity at a point that I am aware of:

Let $I$ be an open interval and $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $I$. Then with respect to $I$

1. a point $x_0 \in I$ is a point of convexity of $f$ if
   \begin{equation}
     f(x_0) \le tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2)
   \end{equation}
   for any $x_1,x_2 \in I$ and $0 < t < 1$ such that $x_0=tx_1 + (1-t)x_2$.
2. $f$ is convex at $x_0\in I$ if for any $x_1 \in I$ other
   than $x_0$, and $0 < t < 1$,
   \begin{equation}
     f(tx_0+(1-t)x_1) \le tf(x_0) + (1-t)f(x_1).  \label{eq:convexbaz}
   \end{equation}
3. $f$ is punctually convex (or p-convex, for short) at $x_0\in I$ if
   \begin{equation}
       f(x_0) + f(x_1+x_2-x_0) \le f(x_1) + f(x_2)
       \label{ineq:punctual-convex}
     \end{equation}
   whenever $x_0$ is strictly between $x_1,x_2 \in I$.
4. $f$ is totally convex at $x_0\in I$ if $\varphi(x,x_0):=\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is an increasing function of $x$ on $I\setminus \{x_0\}$. Equivalently, $\Psi(x_0,x_1,x_2):=\dfrac{\varphi(x_2,x_0)-\varphi(x_1,x_0)}{x_2-x_1} \ge 0$ for any distinct $x_1,x_2$ in $I \setminus\{x_0\}$.

The first one appears in "The mechanics and thermodynamics of continuous media" by M.Šilhavý. It also appears in "Relative convexity and its applications, Aequat. Math., 89, 1389–1400 (2015)" by C. P. Niculescu and I.Roventa.

The second one, as pointed out in a previous reply, appears in "Nonlinear programming. Theory and algorithms" by M.S. Bazaraa, and C.M. Shetty.

The third one appears in "On a class of punctual convex functions, Math. Inequal. Appl., 17, 389–399 (2014)" by  A. Florea and E Paltanea.

The fourth one appears in "Bull. Math. Soc. Sci. Math. Roumanie (N.S.) 66(114) (2023), no. 2, 235–250" by W.Pong and S. Raianu. The relations between these notions are discussed in the article.

Comment: A few examples would greatly complement this answer.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro There are plenty examples in the article by Pong and Raianu. The link was provide in Dave L. Renfro's comment above.